# (Visual Studio 2015) Unable to create Win32 C++ app

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I have visual studio 2015 community Update 2.
I've installed Visual C++ for windows and also for mobile platforms as you can see in this picture:

[image: (Text is in italian)]

The problem is that when I try to create a C++ Win32 app and click on these two templates

[image]

nothing happens and I get stuck at that screen.

Comment: Sounds like an installation/configuration problem. Try repairing the installation, or if there's no repair option, and I know this hurts (maybe hours), reinstall. By the way, for GUI API level desktop app you may want  to use my convenient template; just  check the online templates in VS.

Comment: I'll try reinstalling C++ componets. By the way I don't really need GUI, I want use the Win32 project template to create a DLL for Unity3D.

Comment: @xDevily won't that add a main or winmain entry point instead of dll entry points?

Comment: I checked "Black Project" during the creation of the dll so vs did not create any file.

Comment: Did you select "empty" project after clicking on next and before clicking on finish? After this, you can use "add existing item" to add your source file(s).

Comment: its not a good solution `(The current resolution is to create a project in safe mode

Procedure

Run visual studio command prompt
Type in: devenv /Safemode
Create a new project
The project should now be accessible by going through the standard way of opening visual studio)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Cheers and hth Alf said, I had to reinstall the whole Visual Studio 2015 to get it working again.